# Вводятся имена : Женя Вася Коля Петя. Если найдётся хоть одно у которого совпадают 1 и последняя буквы вывести: ДА, иначе вывести: НЕТ

Tags: python

```
lst = list(map(str, input().lower().split()))
k = 0
a = 0

while k<len(lst):
     
    if k==len(lst):
        print('НЕТ')
        break
    
         
    if lst[k][0]==lst[k][-1]:
        a += 1
    k = k + 1   
    if a==1:
        print('ДА')
        break
```

Comment: А в чём вопрос? На что-то жалуетесь?

Comment: @Alpensin вопрос в том, что `print('НЕТ')` никогда не печатает.

Comment: У вас условие цикла (`k<len(lst)`) противоречит условию `k==len(lst)`. Из-за этого и не выводится

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
#lst = list(map(str, input().lower().split()))
lst = ['женя', 'вася', 'александра', 'коля', 'петя']

for item in lst:
    if item[0] == item[-1]:
        print(f'{item}: {item[0]} = {item[-1]}') # 
        print('ДА')
        break 
else:
    print('НЕТ')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

```
names = input().lower().split()

for name in names:
    if name[0] == name[-1]:
        print("ДА")
        break
else:
    print("НЕТ")
```

---

Объяснение:

1. Не надо применить `map(str, input()...)`, т.к. функция `input()` по определению уже возвращает тип строки (`str`).
2. В цикле `for` допускается ветвь `else`, которая выполнится только в случае, когда цикл `for` вполне исчерпался (т.е. когда команда `break` не совершилась — не появилось ни одно имя с совпадающей первой и последней буквой).

Answer (score 0):

```py
names = ['Женя', 'Вася', 'Александра', 'Коля', 'Петя']

def compare(word: str):
    first, *_, last = word.lower()
    return 'ДА' if first == last else 'НЕТ'


print(
    *map(compare, names),
    sep='\n'
)
```